# Running .sh file when loading web page

Tags: html, debian

I want it so whenever the person will load my webpage, it will run a .sh file, which will fetch a json file using cURL. That json will be stored as a file.

The problem is, how to run it and to not make it visible, as i am using an api key to get the JSON file

Comment: Where is that runs (in client side or backend) ?

Comment: Are you using any server side language for the site or it's a static HTML page? What web server are you using?

Comment: What is your server side scripting language?? PHP?

Comment: @LakmalVithanage Backends

Comment: @sc3w currently only using html and css, using apache@debian

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna i havent gotten into using php

Comment: @sc3w I am using debian, can you tell me where i find the config file, and how to specify the directory of the .sh file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mode_actions` module from Apache to run a shell script whenever your server receives a `GET` request.

You can do it by putting something like this in Apache's config file:

`Script GET "/cgi-bin/download_json.sh"`

More details here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_actions.html